# jqgrid delete a row of the table

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a problem with deleting rows of a table.

I have two tables.

First table contains data from my local DB.

If I choose checkbox and clicked approval, selected row would be copied to second table with type named approval (If I click settlement, its type would be settlement).

[image]
[image]

When I try to make delete function works, either it deletes wrong value, or does not delete any row.

Following is my code:

```
var common = {
        basUrl : function (){
            var l = window.location;
            var url =  "/" + l.pathname.split('/')[1] + "/";
            return url;
        },
        init : function(){
            common.validator();
            common.initDialog();
            common.extendJqgrid();
            common.bindEvent();
            common.datePicker();
            common.initButton();
            common.searchGrid();
            common.initGrid();
        },

        initGrid : function() {

            $("#employeeList").jqGrid(
                    {
                        url: "<c:url value='/app/getGrid'/>",
                        colNames : ['id', 'Department', 'Position', 'Employee'],
                        colModel : [
                                 {
                                    name : 'employeeId',
                                    index : 'employeeId',
                                    hidden : true,
                                    key : true
                                 },
                                 {
                                    name : 'department',
                                    index : 'department',
                                    width : 280,
                                    align : "center",
                                 },
                                 {
                                    name : 'position',
                                    index : 'position',
                                    width : 280,
                                    align : "center",
                                 },
                                 {
                                    name : 'employeeName',
                                    index : 'employeeName',
                                    width : 280,
                                    align : "center",
                                 }, 
                         ],
                         rowNum : 10,
                         multiselect : true,
                         multiboxonly: true,
                         pager : '#pager3',
                         viewrecords : true,
                         sortname : 'department',
                         sortorder : "asc",
                         search : false,
                         onSelectRow : function(id, status, e){
                             var selectRowId = $("#employeeList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                             if (selectRowId != null) {
                                $("#btnApprovalCon, #btnSettlementCon, #btnEnforcementCon, #btnReferenceCon").button("option", "disabled", false);
                             } else {
                                $("#btnApprovalCon, #btnSettlementCon, #btnEnforcementCon, #btnReferenceCon").button("option", "disabled", true);
                                var rowData = null;
                             }
                         },
                         onSelectAll : function(rowId, status) {
                            if (status){
                                $("#btnApprovalCon, #btnSettlementCon, #btnEnforcementCon, #btnReferenceCon").button("option", "disabled", false);
                             } else {
                                $("#btnApprovalCon, #btnSettlementCon, #btnEnforcementCon, #btnReferenceCon").button("option", "disabled", true);
                             }
                         },
                         gridComplete : function(){
                             $("#btnApprovalCon").on('click', function(selrow) {

                                    var list = $("#employeeList").jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selarrrow'); //arrayList
                                    if(list != null){
                                        $.each(list, function(i,v){
                                                var rowData = $("#employeeList").jqGrid('getRowData', v);
                                                console.log(rowData);
                                                var rowCount = $("#reportingList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
                                                var rowNum = rowCount + 1;
                                                var data = {appset_employeeId: rowData.employeeId, appset_department: rowData.department, appset_position:rowData.position, appset_employeeName:rowData.employeeName, type:'Approval'}
                                                $("#reportingList").jqGrid('addRowData', rowData.id, data);
                                        });
                                    }

                                });
                             $("#btnSettlementCon").on('click', function(selrow) {
                                    var list = $("#employeeList").jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selarrrow'); //arrayList(object)
                                    if(list != null){
                                        $.each(list, function(i,v){
                                                var rowData = $("#employeeList").jqGrid('getRowData', v);
                                                console.log(rowData);
                                                var rowCount = $("#reportingList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
                                                var rowNum = rowCount + 1;
                                                var data = {appset_employeeId: rowData.employeeId, appset_orderNumber: rowNum,  appset_department: rowData.department, appset_position:rowData.position, appset_employeeName:rowData.employeeName, type:'Settlement'}
                                                $("#reportingList").jqGrid('addRowData', rowData.id, data);
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                         }
                    }).navGrid("#pager3", { search:false, edit:false, add:false, del:false});   

            $("#reportingList").jqGrid(
                    {
                        colNames : ['id', 'Department', 'Position', 'Employee', 'Type'],
                        colModel : [
                         {
                            name : 'appset_employeeId',
                            index : 'appset_employeeId',
                            hidden : true,
                            key : true
                         },
                         {
                            name : 'appset_department',
                            index : 'appset_department',
                            width : 210,
                            align : "center",
                         },
                         {
                            name : 'appset_position',
                            index : 'appset_position',
                            width : 210,
                            align : "center",
                         },
                         {
                            name : 'appset_employeeName',
                            index : 'appset_employeeName',
                            width : 210,
                            align : "center",
                         },
                         {
                            name : 'type',
                            index : 'type',
                            width : 210,
                            align : "center",
                         }, ],
                         rowNum : 10,
                         multiselect : true,
                         multiboxonly: true,
                         pager : '#pager4',
                         viewrecords : true,
                         search : false,
                         viewrecords : true,
                         onSelectRow : function(id, status, e){
                             var selectRowId = $("#reportingList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                             if (selectRowId != null) {
                                $("#btnAppSetDel").button("option", "disabled", false);
                             } else {
                                $("#btnAppSetDel").button("option", "disabled", true);
                                var rowData = null;
                             }
                         },
                         onSelectAll : function(rowId, status) {
                            if (status){
                                $("#btnAppSetDel").button("option", "disabled", false);
                             } else {
                                $("#btnAppSetDel").button("option", "disabled", true);
                             }
                         },
                         gridComplete : function(selrow){
                            $("#btnAppSetDel").on('click', function() {
                                var list = $("#employeeList").jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selarrrow'); //arrayList(object)

                                $("#reportingList").jqGrid('delRowData', 'selarrow');
                                /*
                                if(list != null){
                                    $.each(list, function(i,v){
                                        $("#reportingList").jqGrid('delRowData', 'v');
                                    });
                                }
                                */
                            });
                         }
                    }).navGrid("#pager4", { search:false, edit:false, add:false, del:true});

            $("#reportingList").sortableRows();
            $("#reportingList").jqGrid('gridDnD');
        },
```

I tried to import delRowData, but I do not sure if I used it properly.

May I ask you what I suppose to do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the origin of your problem is the id duplicates. You have two grids on the same page. Both the grids have the column with the `key: true` property (`employeeId` in the first grid and `appset_employeeId` in the second grid). I suppose that you can have **the same id values** for the rows of both grids.

To protect your project from such problem you should use `idPrefix` option in at least one grid. For example you can use `idPrefix: "g1_"` in the first grid and `idPrefix: "g2_"` in the second one. The `idPrefix` option will informs jqGrid to build rowid based on the `key: true`, but using the specified prefix. It will make the rowids different in both grids.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'm leaving now to go back home, so I will try it after an hour when I get back to my place.  So if I understand it correctly, all I have to do is put idPrefix: "g1_", above rowNum : 10, of the first grid?

Comment: @user2130466: Yes, I would recommend you to try this first of all.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not fix my problem.

Comment: @user2130466: If you want to solve the problem then you should post more details about what you do. You should **always** write which version of jqGrid and which fork you use for your tests. For example I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork. Could you repeat your test using URLs to jqGrid files described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit)? If you would have the same problem with free jqGrid then I can analyse the problem and fix jqGrid code if it have the bug. I'll need the demo.

Comment: It's fine Oleg, I will just try to figure this out tomorrow morning.  Thank you for your help today.